# How to hide modem setting page from public IP

Tags: security, networking, ip, modem, localserver

I have a problem setting up a test server on my local machine, whenever I open my public IP (122.168.XXX.XXX) from a web-browser it opens my D-Link modem setting page instead of denied access. It means that my modem setting page is open to public and anyone can access it also modify my settings, upgrade firmware and break into my system (I think it doesn't take time to crack the only password layer, between an attacker and my modem/network), please provide me some tips so that I save myself from an attacker or how to block access of modem setting page from public IP and only allow access to local IP. ( and if possible some tutorials for setting up a home server using apache). my modem - d-link , model name - DSL-2730U

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve the problem, what I did was just forwarded port 80 to my local machine from modem setting page and started xampp server locally.